# How to convert a dict inside a list to a DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Python beginner here. I am struggling to dump my `list` of `dicts` into a `pandas.DataFrame` the right away. My data has the following structure.

```
a = {'Scores': {'s1': [{'Math': '95',
'Science': '74.5',                  
'English': '60.5'},                         
{'Math': '87.9',              
'Science': '97.3',                  
'English': '78.3'}],                        
's2': [{'Math': '67.2',       
'Science': '74.2',                        
'English': '89'}]}}
```

My `pandas.Dataframe` columns should be the subjects 'Math', 'Science' and 'English' and the rows should be the scores. The columns are dynamically created so I can not explicitly mention the column names to call it. All I need are the values of keys S1.... Sn.

This what I have tried so far:

```
b = a.pop('Scores')
c = list(b.values())
df = pd.DataFrame(c)
```

This displays my dataframe as:

```
                                               0  \
0  {'Math': '95', 'Science': '74.5', 'English': '...
1  {'Math': '67.2', 'Science': '74.2', 'English':...

                                               1
0  {'Math': '87.9', 'Science': '97.3', 'English':...
1                                               None
```

Instead, I am looking for:

```
Math  Science  English
95    74.5     60.5
87.9  97.3     78.3
67.2  74.2     89
```

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sum after iterating over the values of the dict.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = sum([x for x in a['Scores'].values()], [])
print(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Math', 'Science', 'English']))
```

**Test Data:**

```
a = {'Scores': {'s1': [{'Math': '95',
                        'Science': '74.5',
                        'English': '60.5'},
                       {'Math': '87.9',
                        'Science': '97.3',
                        'English': '78.3'}],
                's2': [{'Math': '67.2',
                        'Science': '74.2',
                        'English': '89'}]}}
```

**Result:**

```
   Math Science English
0  67.2    74.2      89
1    95    74.5    60.5
2  87.9    97.3    78.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just extract all the scores with a comprehension/generator:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(s for k, v in a['Scores'].items() for s in v)
  English  Math Science
0    60.5    95    74.5
1    78.3  87.9    97.3
2      89  67.2    74.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to `apply` yourself

```
pd.Series(a['Scores']).apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series)

     English  Math Science
s1 0    60.5    95    74.5
   1    78.3  87.9    97.3
s2 0      89  67.2    74.2
```